# How to write CSV file on azure file storage account using java?

Tags: java, azure

The way we create CSV file to specified path on our system like in one drive and some folder path we use FileWriter specifying filePath while creating FileWriter object. Similary how can we create CSV file in azure file storage using java?

I am working on spring mvc hibernate application where I need to read the data from SQL server and write that data to csv file and place that file to a location.
That code is already there. But I need to write this data to a azure file storage location now. Let say this is the code

```
    String csvFile = "/Users/amar/csv/developer.csv";
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);

    List<Developer> developers = Arrays.asList(
            new Developer("amar", new BigDecimal(120500), 32),
            new Developer("zilap", new BigDecimal(150099), 5),
            new Developer("ultraman", new BigDecimal(99999), 99)
    );

    //for header
    CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("Name", "Salary", "Age"));

    for (Developer d : developers) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(d.getName());
        list.add(d.getSalary().toString());
        list.add(String.valueOf(d.getAge()));

        CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list);

        //try custom separator and quote.
        //CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list, '|', '\"');
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

now instead of `writer.flush()` I want to do something like

```
CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(path); 

cloudFile = sampleDir.getFileReference("csvfile.csv");
cloudFile.write(csvfile);
```

something like this.

so my question is what is the replacement of csv filewriter in azure api for java.

Comment: You need to tell more. Please tell us what kind of application you're building, where it is running (Azure VM/WebApp etc.), and what have you tried so far. As it stands now, there are not much details available for us to answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, [Azure File storage SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/tree/master/microsoft-azure-storage-test/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/file) does not provide a method similar to 
`file.write(file)`.

According to your code, it seems that you created a local file and write data into it. Then you could use `uploadFromPath` method to upload your file into Azure File Storage.

Sample code as below :

```
String csvFile = "/Users/amar/csv/developer.csv";
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);

List<Developer> developers = Arrays.asList(
        new Developer("amar", new BigDecimal(120500), 32),
        new Developer("zilap", new BigDecimal(150099), 5),
        new Developer("ultraman", new BigDecimal(99999), 99)
);

//for header
CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("Name", "Salary", "Age"));

for (Developer d : developers) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(d.getName());
    list.add(d.getSalary().toString());
    list.add(String.valueOf(d.getAge()));

    CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list);

    //try custom separator and quote.
    //CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list, '|', '\"');
}

writer.flush();
writer.close();

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("test");

CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();    

CloudFile file = rootDir.getFileReference("test.csv");

file.uploadFromPath(csvFile);
```

In addition, you could use `upload` method to upload `stream` to Azure File Storage directly.

Snippet of code:

```
file.upload( new StringBufferInputStream("aaa"),"aaa".length());
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Jay Gong for responding quickly. But our requirement is to create csv file directly to azure file storage. Actually the idea is not to use local file system.

Comment: @ShashiShekhar   Then, maybe you could consider using the stream method I mentioned in my answer to upload data to Azure File Storage